# Access tabbed form: keep focus on the top of the form

Tags: ms-access

I created a tabbed form in Microsoft Access. The form has seven tab pages each tab page has a number of subforms. The problem is when I move from tab page to tab page the form opens in the middle of the page and requires scrolling up to see top of the form and the tabs of tabcontrol. From my search, I understand this can happen because the form is extra long. I do not want to resize the form as it has to be that long.  I checked the tab order of each tab page and all controls are in the right order. My question is how can I force the focus to be on the top of the form when moving between tab pages?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that worked for me. Putting a control at the top of the tab order list does not mean that you will get the focus at the top of the tab page.  It seems that Access automatically put the focus on the last created control. What I have done is to create an unbound text box with width and height 0 - to be hidden - and I placed it at the top of my form inside each of the tab page. It is important to check that it is at the bottom of the tab order list in each page, job done!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found an easy fix to it. I had 4 subforms on one tab page (2 at the top (order nr. 0 and 1) and 2 at the bottom (order nr. 2 and 3)). When moving between tabs and going back to my tab with all the subforms, Access just sets the focus in the middle of the page or, to be more precise, where subforms with order nr. 2,3 are.
After checking a million times the orders, I found this solution:

1. Select the subforms that are at the bottom (in my case the subforms with order nr. 2 and 3)
   2.Go to properties > Other > change "In Order" to "No".

Answer (score 0):

The user14048847 answer is nearly correct. It should be:
2.Go to properties > Other > change "Tab Stop" to "No".